# new line command not working in php

Tags: php

I am trying to write in a text file and after each line is written the next line will be in the new line. But when i check my txt file, it is showing every entry in the same line. Although \t is working, there is a tab in between each field. Here is my code

```
foreachloop{    
$fp=fopen("order.txt", "a");
fwrite($fp,$item_name."\t".$item_price."\t" .$each_item['quantity']."\t"     .$total_price."\t" .$fname."\n");


    $i++;
}//end of for each loop
fclose($fp);
print "added";
```

Comment: What's your OS? What's your editor, and finally, have you checked with a hex editor if `\n` is present?

Comment: 1. On what platform are you developing/testing?
2. What program are you using to open the text file?

Comment: try \n\r  (new line and return)

Comment: You should do this with `fwritecsv`.

Comment: @NawedKhan it should be \r\n (other way around)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all operating systems use `"\n"` as the line delimiter. Use `PHP_EOL` to insert the end-of-line character(s) appropriate for your operating system.

```
fwrite($fp, $item_name . "..." . $fname . PHP_EOL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace "\n" with the defined [**PHP_EOL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php)